# Simple line of code to redo I forget the name

Tags: php

I forgot how to do the following or what it is called.... instead of writing the code like:

```
if ( $row['level'] != 1 && $row['level'] != 2 && $row['level'] != 3 ) 
{

}
```

There was a way to make the code above look better.  I think it was all put into an array or something.  Could you please provide me with the code to make the above look cleaner?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you searching for [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)?

```
if(!in_array($row['level'], array(1,2,3))) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $row['level'] > 3 ) 
{

}
```

Maybe?

Comment: No there was an array used or something so that I dont have to keep rewritting all of the code.  Ignore the actual value this is just an example.